# How to detect an account change in MetaMask using Meteor and web3?

Tags: javascript, meteor, solidity, web3js, metamask

I am creating a DApp using meteor in which a templateVar displays an account address.

Using a web3 function in JavaScript I defined the `updateInterface()` method as seen below as updateInterface()

However, since the method is a loop I can't seem to trigger the event inside `Template.foo.events`. The method works as I am able to `alert(res)` alert the result onto the screen.

Could somebody point me in the right direction? cheers

Here is the `template.oncreated` function and also the function `updateInterface()` is placed outside the `oncreated`, helper and events methods.

```
Template.foo.onCreated(function fooOnCreated() {
    this.account= new ReactiveVar(0);
});

Template.foo.helpers({
    account() {
        var template = Template.instance();
        myContract = web3.eth.contract(ABIArray).at(contractAddress);

        var result = web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, res) {
            TemplateVar.set(template, "person", res);
        });
    },
}); 

Template.foo.events({
      // not sure what to place here
});

var account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
var accountInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (web3.eth.accounts[0] !== account) {
        account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
        updateInterface();
    }
}, 100);

function updateInterface() {
    var template = Template.instance();
    var result = web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, res) {
        alert(res);
        TemplateVar.set(template, "account", res);
    });
}
```

The problem with events is that it requires an event, whereas the metamask detection function detects a change in account every **100 milliseconds**, I am not sure where to place the `updateInterface()` method.

TemplateVar points here.

```
<head>
    <body>
        <div id="section">
            {{>foo}}
        </div>
    </body>
</head>

<template name="foo">
    <div id="location">
        <p>Currently logged in as: {{account}} {{TemplateVar.get 
           "account"}} </p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Ok I will try to reproduce but one thing is missing, where and how do you exactly declare `TemplateVar`?

Comment: I followed a tutorial ( [link](https://youtu.be/srPNAwzRuB4?t=125) to around 3:24 ) that used an addon on meteor by running <code>meteor add frozeman:template-var</code> It points to a location in html. I have edited the code again to demonstrate where I put it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the interval loop inside of the `onCreated` and instead of checking `account !== web3.eth.accounts[0]` you should check `self.account.get() = web3.eth.accounts[0]`

like this

```
Template.foo.onCreated(function fooOnCreated() {
  this.account= new ReactiveVar(0);
  this.account.set(web3.eth.accounts[0]);
  var self = this;
  var accountInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (web3.eth.accounts[0] !== self.account.get()) {
      self.account.set(web3.eth.accounts[0]);
    }
  }, 500);
});
```

and because it is a `ReactiveVar` you don't have to call the update function. The template should update automatically as the value is used in it.

I have not tested it but I think it should work like this